# Windows CE 6.0 DLL import to Windows 7

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, windows-ce, dllimport

I have a legacy application written in WINCE 6.0.
I want to make a similar Windows 7 desktop application so that I can run the application from any standard Windows machine.

The problem is this Win CE application uses a DLL for doing some security key generation.

Can I use import this WIN CE DLL and use its functions in the Windows desktop application?

Comment: Does this external DLL exist for desktop Windows? Do you have source code of this DLL? If no you are in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use import this WIN CE DLL and use its functions in the Windows desktop application?

No you cannot. Windows CE executable modules cannot be executed on Windows desktop platforms.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the source of this DLL then I think your only option is to run the CE application inside an emulator running on your PC.  You can get a Windows Mobile emulator program named Microsoft Device Emulator.  CE emulators are usually provided by the OEM.  If you have the source to the DLL then you can try compiling it for desktop Windows.